# Using functional interface as parameters to filter() function in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, functional-interface

This is a code snippet that tries to use a functional interface inside the filter function.

```
Function<Path, Boolean> isNotPartitionFile = (path) -> {
    return !path.toString().contains("partition");
};

List<Path> pathsList =  Files.walk(Paths.get(extractFilesLocation))
                                 .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                                 .filter(isNotPartitionFile)
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

When I try to use the `isNotPartitionFile` as a parameter to the `filter()` function, eclipse pops up an error that says `The method filter(Predicate<? super Path>) in the type Stream<Path> is not applicable for the arguments (Function<Path,Boolean>)`. It also suggests to cast to `(Predicate<? super Path>)` , but this throws a runtime error that says it cannot be casted. 
How do I overcome this ?

Comment: Why are you storing it as a `Function` instead of a `Predicate`?

Comment: Why is `isNotPartitionFile` declared as `Function<Path, Boolean>`? Wouldn't it be simpler to change it to `Predicate<Path>`?

Comment: For better or for worse, `Predicate<T>` does not extend `Function<T, Boolean>`. Use `Predicate<Path>`.

Comment: There are no errors, this works fine in eclipse.

Comment: @RavindraRanwala Are you sure? `filter` expects `Predicate`, there is no `filter` allowing `Function<Whatever,Boolean>` so how can it work in eclipse if `Function<Whatever,Boolean>` isn't subtype of any `Predicate`?

Comment: Now it gives the error. Previously he has casted it to a predicate.

Comment: Casting it to a Predicate wouldn't work either.  Casting it _and_ using a method reference would work, though.

Comment: BTW `if (condition) return true; else return false` can be simplified as `return condition;`. Since lambda `(arguments)->{return value;}` can be simplified as `(arguments)->value` you can rewrite it as `path -> !path.toString().contains("partition");`

Answer (score 2):

`isNotPartitionFile`  should be defined as:

```
Predicate<Path> isNotPartitionFile = path -> !path.toString().contains("partition");
```

because `filter` consumes a `Predicate<T>` not `Function<T, R>`.

Answer (score 1):

`Predicate` is a function that takes in a value and always return `boolean`. `.filter` is expecting a `Predicate<T>` and not a `Function<T, Boolean>`. The reason `Predicate<T>` doesn't extend `Function<T, Boolean>` is because `Predicate<T>` returns `boolean` which can never be null. To fix your issue, you could change your `isNotPartitionFile` to

```
Predicate<Path> isNotPartitionFile = (path) -> path.toString().contains("partition");
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution myself.

The `filter` function expects a function as a parameter, but a functional interface was passed. So it needs to be replaced with the `apply` function of the `Function` interface.

```
List<Path> pathsList =  Files.walk(Paths.get(extractFilesLocation))
                                 .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                                 .filter(isNotPartitionFile::apply)
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: "*The filter function expects a function as a parameter, but a functional interface was passed*" doesn't make much sense and suggests you are misunderstanding *functional interface*. *Functional* doesn't mean that interface must be of type `Function`, but that interface must have only *one abstract method*. So `Function<A,B>` is functional interface because but only because it has precisely one abstract method: `B apply(A a)`. Also `Predicate<A>` is functional interface because it holds precisely one abstract method representing `A -> boolean` mapping. Similarly `Supplier` and `Consumer`.

Comment: Now `isNotPartitionFile::apply` will work in your case because it will represent something like `Predicate<Path> predicate = (path) -> isNotPartitionFile.apply(path)`.

Answer (score 1):

[`Stream<T> filter(Predicate<? super T> predicate)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) apply Predicate as parameter.

**Predicate**  is a boolean-valued function.

Try this:

```
Predicate<Path> isNotPartitionFile = path -> !path.toString().contains("partition");
```